# newline doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, newline

When I use the new line character in java-script it is not working. I post my code below.

```
var i=1;
while(i<=5)
{
    document.write(i+"\n");     
    i++;
}
```

The outcome looks like this.
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Try `document.write(i+"<br/>");`

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.  It contains code to reproduce the problem, an explanation of the current behavior, and the desired result.  I've seen far worse.

Comment: If you view the source of your page, you will notice that your source contains the new lines. The problem is not that the `\n` wasn't written to the document, it's that HTML ignores the newline character.

Comment: It's really a very basic question about how html documents are displayed.  The problem really has nothing to do with javascript, a better question title would be "How do I display a line break in html?"

Answer (score 3):

since you are writing into HTML Document, you should write `<br>`

```
var i=1;
while(i<=5){
 document.write(i+"<br/>");     
 i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"\n"`, use `"<br/>"`, as the code below:

```
var i=1;
while(i<=5)
{
    document.write(i+"<br/>");     
    i++;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3CKz/) is the JSFiddle. When accessing it, click run to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are not seeing the newline characters as you expected is because you are likely trying to render this in HTML. If that is the case, "\n" is not rendered as a newline. Which is why @Yuriy Galanter said to include `<br/>` which *is*. If you were to write to the `console.log` then it would work as you have it written.